# SELECT MAX(...) incorrectly returns NULL in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-null

I have a table, `ga_sum_1`, with a column, `created_timestamp` in it. When I execute the following query from the mysql command line:

```
mysql> select max(created_timestamp) from ga_sum_1;
+------------------------+
| max(created_timestamp) |
+------------------------+
| 2017-11-05 00:59:55    |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And if I do the same from a very simple stored procedure:

```
delimiter //
create procedure test()
begin
  select max(created_timestamp) from ga_sum_1;
end//
delimiter ;

mysql> call test();
+------------------------+
| max(created_timestamp) |
+------------------------+
| 2017-11-05 00:59:55    |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But, when I so the same from within a stored procedure:

```
drop procedure if exists test;

delimiter //

create procedure test()
begin
  declare cursor_end condition for sqlstate '02000';
  declare finished int default 0;
  declare game_id int(11);
  declare user_id int(11);
  declare game_instance_id bigint(20);
  declare currency varchar(15);
  declare created_timestamp timestamp;
  declare wager decimal(18,2);
  declare win decimal(18,2);
  -- cursor
  declare game_action_csr cursor for select * from game_action_view;
  declare continue handler for cursor_end set finished=1;

  -- create view dynamically
select max(created_timestamp) from ga_sum_1;

end//

delimiter ;

mysql> call test();
+------------------------+
| max(created_timestamp) |
+------------------------+
| NULL                   |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

What am I doing wrong in the last example?

====EDIT====

Some further research shows that it is the `declare created_timestamp` - apparently that confuses the select on the column of the same name!

Comment: Just a note... while MySQL could be much better about those kinds of ambiguities (it could at least complain), many of these can be avoided by making a habit of prefixing field names with name/alias of their table (admittedly harder to force yourself to do with single table queries).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's probably because of this line:

```
  declare created_timestamp timestamp;
```

Comment: Yeah - I was just updating my question with the same observation - thanks!

Comment: *"I was just updating my question with the same observation"* @j4nd3r53n it's better to prefix the `declare` with something like `declare t_created_timestamp timestamp;` so you know those are internal "temporary" variables if you make a habit out off it you are less likely to make this mistake again.

Comment: Well @j4nd3r53n i wished MySQL optimizer was smarter in mine my opinion the optimizer should/could see `created_timestamp` exists in two different "namespaces" one as table column name and one as stored procedure variable.

Comment: In some environments this ambiguity is resolved by looking at the closest namespace. Why MySQL prefers the scope variable over the column name is beyond me. I would consider the variable name further away from the query compared to the column name.

Comment: @SalmanA probably because a column name can be specified by prefixing with it's table's name/alias, where no similar method of disambiguation is present for local variables or paramters. While the field name is the closest "namespace", presuming the field would leave no way to express that you intended to reference the local variable.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternate to the other answer, your could simply be more specific:

```
select max(ga_sum_1.created_timestamp) from ga_sum_1
```